# getting percentage amount of data from a list

Tags: c#, linq, math, .net-core

I have Post mode

```
public class Post{
    public bool IsHomePage {get;set;}
    public bool IsBreakingNews {get;set;}
    public bool Title {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

The idea is to get a certain amount (percentage amount) of posts using type (IsHomePage, IsBreakingNews, ....)

I'm retrieveing data

```
var posts = repository.GetAll();

int pctHomePagePosts = 25; //%
int pctBreakingNews = 40;  //%

var listWithPctHomePagePosts = posts.Take(posts.Count / 25);
```

> operator / cannot be applied to operands of type method group or int

Comment: when dealing with percentages you should definitly change one of your operands to `float` or `double`. Otherwise you get integer-division, which usually results in zero (e.g. 30/100 = 0, not 0.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this.

**To get 25%**

```
var listWithPctHomePagePosts = posts.Take((decimal)(posts.Count() * (pctHomePagePosts / 100)));
```

**To get 40%**

```
var listWithPctBreakingNews = posts.Take((decimal)(posts.Count() * (pctBreakingNews / 100)));
```

Comment: Those two lines will both give a result of `0` as written, because the two `pct...` variables are both an `int` less than 100 and you are dividing them by 100.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you want to refer to the `Count` method exposed by Linq:

```
var listWithPctHomePagePosts = posts.Take(posts.Count() / 25);
```

Comment: So if there are fewer than 25 posts, this will always take 0 of them.

Comment: @MatthewWatson you're right: I was aware just to the mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

try this (if total of items is 60, 25 for isHome and 40 for isBreaking) then:

```
var posts = repository.GetAll(); //65 items   
int HomePagePostsPercentage = (int) (posts.Where(x => x.IsHomePage == true).Count() / posts.Count()) * 100; //val = 25
int pctBreakingNewsCount = (int) (posts.Where(x => x.IsBreakingNews == true).Count() / posts.Count()) * 100; //val = 40
var listWithPctHomePagePosts = posts.Take(posts.Count() / 25);
```

---

if you want just to filter out items with IsHomePage  is true, then just do:

```
var HomePagePostsItesm = posts.Where(x => x.IsHomePage == true).ToList();
```